# New AWS ECS Cluster created and no EC2 Instance added to the cluster?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I see that the autoscaling group successfully created the EC2 instance but it didn't include it in the cluster? What can I do to fix this issue?

Things I've verified:

- I did choose network and ec2 linux
- The instance is currently running with 2/2 status check
- I did see this question but the answers there were not the issue: [EC2 instances not created while creating ECS cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57525686/ec2-instances-not-created-while-creating-ecs-cluster)

Comment: Probably due to a network configuration that is blocking the ECS agent running on the EC2 instance from connecting to the ECS service. Does the subnet have a route to the ECS service somehow? Any NACL rules? Any outbound traffic blocked in the Security Group?

Comment: Thanks @MarkB, I started a new cluster with a new VPC and it worked this time.